# Powershell and iTextsharp add multiple images to PDF

Tags: powershell, pdf, itext

I'm trying to use itextsharp (could change to pdfsharp if that would be a better option) in Powershell to make a PDF out of a images. I've managed to create a PDF-file with one image but I don't know how to create one from all images in a folder.

As these images are in scale to fit a PDF perfectly, I would also like to set the scale so it fills up the page 100%. Is that possible?

I'm not an experienced Powershell-user but this is what I got so far:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\temp\itextsharp.dll")

$doc = New-Object iTextSharp.text.Document
$fileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream("C:\temp\output5.pdf", [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
[iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter]::GetInstance($doc, $filestream)

$jpg = [iTextSharp.text.Image]::GetInstance( "c:\temp\horse.jpg" )
$doc.open()
$Doc.add($jpg);
$doc.close()
```

If anyone has any idea, please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [`Get-ChildItem`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) to get all of the images in a given folder. You'll then want to use [`ForEach-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176828.aspx) (sometimes shortened to `foreach`) on the images calling your `$doc.Add()` but right before also calling `$doc.NewPage()`.

The below code shows this all off. One common request is to also have each page sized to fit the image so I've added that, too. We instantiate a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` with each image to get the dimensions, create an iTextSharp `Rectangle` with those dimensions and then use that to set the page's size via `$doc.SetPageSize()`.

I've moved most of the variable to the top just to make things easier, you'll want to update them to match your needs. The comments should hopefully get you the rest of the way.

```
## Set various paths
$iTextSharpFilePath = "D:\DLLs\itextsharp.dll"
$imageFolderPath    = "D:\images"
$pdfFilePath        = "D:\temp.pdf"

## Load iTextSharp and System.Drawing
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($iTextSharpFilePath)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

## Get all of the images in the folder
## Change the filter if needed
$images = Get-ChildItem $imageFolderPath -Filter *.png

## Create our stream, document and bind a writer
$fileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($pdfFilePath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
$doc = New-Object iTextSharp.text.Document
$writer = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter]::GetInstance($doc, $filestream)

## Open the document for writing
$doc.Open()

## Remove all document margins
$doc.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

## Loop through each image in the folder
foreach($image in $images)
{
    ## Create a .Net image so that we can get the image dimensions
    $bmp = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($image.FullName)

    ## Create an iTextSharp rectangle that corresponds to those dimensions
    $rect = New-Object iTextSharp.text.Rectangle($bmp.Width, $bmp.Height)

    ## Set the next page size to those dimensions and add a new page
    $doc.SetPageSize( $rect )
    $doc.NewPage()

    ## Add our image to the page
    $doc.Add([iTextSharp.text.Image]::GetInstance( $image.FullName ));

    ## Cleanup
    $bmp.Dispose()
}

## Cleanup
$doc.Close()
$doc.Dispose()
$writer.Dispose()
```