# How to use iTextSharp on Powershell

Tags: powershell, itext

I'm new in PowerShell and I'm trying to edit pdfs using the iTextSharp tool but I cant get it to work, here is what I have so far trying to open a file but it gives me an error

```
$path = "C:\...\Itext\lib\a.pdf" #path to my pdf file

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\...\Itext\lib\itextsharp.dll") #path to my itextsharp.dll
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\...\Itext\lib\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll") #path to my BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll

New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader ("$path")
```

And the error is this:

New-Object : Exception to call ".ctor" with the arguments "1": "Rebuild failed: Dictionary key Virtual is not a name. at file pointer 2516;
Original message: Dictionary key Virtual is not a name. at file pointer 2516"

I hope someone can help me with this, thanks in advance

Comment: This is a setup and use of a 3rdP dll, not really a PowerShell code-specific issue. However, why are you not looking at the iTextSharp help files or the many SO Q&A's, web articles, and [Youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+itextsharp) on using iTextSharp with Powershell? btw, iTextSharp is legacy, and if you go to their site, they tell you to use the new Itext7 instead, for setup and use?

Answer (score 0):

[The error message you are getting is no unique to iTextSharp.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27new-object%20%3A%20exception%20to%20call%20%22.ctor%22%20with%20the%20arguments%20%221%22%3A%20%22rebuild%20failed%3A%20dictionary%20key%20virtual%20is%20not%20a%20name.%20at%20file%20pointer%202516%3B%20original%20message%3A%20dictionary%20key%20virtual%20is%20not%20a%20name.%20at%20file%20pointer%202516%22%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Continuing from my comment.

> https://github.com/itext/itextsharp
>
> PLEASE NOTE: iTextSharp is EOL, and has been replaced by iText 7. Only  security fixes will be added We HIGHLY recommend customers use iText 7 for new projects, and to consider moving existing projects from iTextSharp to iText 7 to benefit from the many improvements such as:

There are many posts, right here on SO regarding iTestSharp and iText7 use cases via PowerShell.

> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+itextsharp
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+itext7
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+using+itextsharp
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+using+itext7

SO Example(s)

> [Powershell and iTextsharp add multiple images to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450351/powershell-and-itextsharp-add-multiple-images-to-pdf)

```
## Set various paths
$iTextSharpFilePath = "D:\DLLs\itextsharp.dll"
$imageFolderPath    = "D:\images"
$pdfFilePath        = "D:\temp.pdf"

## Load iTextSharp and System.Drawing
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($iTextSharpFilePath)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
```

> [How to use Itext7 in powershell V5, Exception when loading pdfWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55915290/how-to-use-itext7-in-powershell-v5-exception-when-loading-pdfwriter)
>
> The problem is that a couple of dependencies are missing. iText7 depends on Common.Logging version 3.4.1 (can be downloaded here), which on turn depends on Common.Logging.Core, same version 3.4.1 (can be downloaded here). Also, make sure the BouncyCastle dependency is  Portable.BouncyCastle version 1.8.1.3 (can be downloaded here).
>
> You don't need the NLog dependency, at least it's not needed for iText 7 to work.
>
> That being said, here is the code snipped that worked fine in my set  up (iText 7.1.6, PowerShell 5.1):

```
[string] $pdfDocuFilename = "C:\temp\" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".pdf"

Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\Common.Logging.Core.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\Common.Logging.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\itext.io.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\itext.kernel.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll"


$pdfWriter = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter]::new($pdfDocuFilename)
$pdf = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($pdfWriter)
$pdf.AddNewPage()
$pdf.Close()
```